# best way to pull ansible playbook down and run it

Tags: ansible

What is the best way to pull a playbook down from bitbucket and execute it using ansible?

description:
I wrote a playbook and have it checked into bitbucket.  I have docker which is spinning up ansible(image) and I need it to pull down the playbook and run a command against it.  Anyone have experience with this??  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ansible-pull http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html or just do a regular git checkout and then run the code. Both work well with a public repo but will require git credentials if the repo is private. If you want to do this with a private repo you will want some form of secrets management for storing a token or ssh key to authenticate with.

Alternatively, at build time you can copy the files you need into the Docker image from your dev machine or CI tool and run the playbook, instead of doing that at runtime. This will decrease the boot time of your docker image as well.

Comment: what's the best way to copy a play book into a docker container and execute it with a single command?  i.e. docker run -it ansible/ubuntu14.04-ansible

Comment: The best way would be to define a Dockerfile that does it for you

Comment: my play-book has configs that constantly change which would result in my building an image every time my continuous build kicks off which could result in a lot of images.  You know of a simpler way?  start up docker.. copy the play book over.. execute my command.. and then docker will be torn down?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to handle configuration management in this case

The top two that come to mind are:
1. Write your application so that it can read config settings from environment variables. Build your image in CI and then at runtime you can pass in environment variables
2. Package a docker image that has your app installed but not configured, then at runtime execute a templated Dockerfile that can configure things the way you want to

Comment: Make the configurations to be dynamic. May be these have to be generated.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
# clone repo
git clone https://bitbucket.org/user/repo.git && cd repo    
docker run --rm=true -v `pwd`:/repo:rw ansible/ubuntu14.04-ansible /bin/bash -c "ansible-playbook -i /repo/hosts /repo/main.yml"
```

PS:
I am using with Travis CI such a way: https://github.com/weldpua2008/ansible-pycharm/blob/master/.travis.yml